# jQuery - on load of element with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I searched for some time but could not find a working solution for my problem (sorry if I searched wrongly)...
I would like to have the equivalent of the following function for an element loaded with ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.div-modal-text').css("background-color","red");
});
```

Therefore I am using the following code:

```
  $('#parent_id').on('action', '#id or class to be born', function to be performed() );
```

In my example the parent-child structure is: #projectModals (div whose content is dynamically loaded)>...>.div-project-description>.div-modal-text

This translates into the following code in my example:

```
  $('#projectModals').on('load', '.div-project-description', function() {  
      $(this).find('.div-modal-text').each(function() { 
           $(this).css("background-color","red");

    });
  });
```

I know 'load' does not work with .on(), but I tried different alternatives and I could not find anything working.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**: Here is my (simplified) HTML code:

```
    <div id="projectModals"></div>
```

content loaded in #projectModals with Ajax:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="div-project-idcard">          
            column 1, don't bother too much about this column            
        </div>
        <div class="div-project-description"> 
          <div id="summary" class="div-modal-text">
            Column2, text 1               
          </div>
          <div id="purpose"  class="div-modal-text"">
            Column2, text 2
          </div>
          <div id="reforestation"  class="div-modal-text">
            Column2, text 3
          </div>
          <div id="certification"  class="div-modal-text">
            Column2, text 4
          </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
```

Comment: would you share your html code as well please?

Comment: Do you always need the same background color for `.div-modal-text`? if so, why don't use only CSS?

Comment: How do you load your content into #projectModals, post that script

Comment: Indeed, I simplified code here to illustrate my problem. In reality there are more conditions before I change the background color

Comment: Just to let you know, to reply to specific people, you can type @ and then their display name, so that they get a notification. I think you meant to reply to @ApulGupta above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're waiting for it to be loaded via ajax, consider using `$(window).ajaxSuccess()` instead:

```
  $(window).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $('#projectModals .div-project-description .div-modal-text').each(function() { 
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
  });
```

Comment: rather `$('#projectModals.div-project-description .div-modal-text').css("background-color","red")`

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

for what I understand, you want to change some background color after an ajax has been executed.

I think it's best to make the operation in the ajax success

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    data: {some data},
    success: onAjaxSuccess,
});
```

and then;

```
function onAjaxSuccess(data){
    //.. do things with data
    var toExecute = $('#projectModals .div-project-description');
    toExecute.find('.div-modal-text').each(function() { 
           $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
}
```